# Jquery not getting the selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the value of selected drop down,the selected value to store in database but it not takeing the selected value below is my code can one guide how to do it.thanks

Updated

**clientnetworkpricelist/update.php**

```
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$client_id=$_POST['clientid'];
    $feild=$_POST['field'];
            $data= $_POST['value'];
            $rownum=$_POST['rowid'];  
            $sql="UPDATE $client_id SET ".$feild." = '".$data."' WHERE net_id = ".$rownum."";

             print $sql;



            mysql_query($sql)

;
```

**Html**

```
<?php
$client_id=$_GET['clientid'];

if($client_id!=""){

$sql=mysql_query("select * from supplierprice a JOIN $client_id b WHERE b.`net_id` = a.`supp_price_id`" );
$query = "SELECT route FROM routestable WHERE `clientid` = '$client_id' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//print "query". $query;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo '   <td  class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["clientid"].'</td>
         <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>  
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_country" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_networkname" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mcc"  class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>   
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnc"  class="'.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnp" class="edit mnp '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>';
  /*                        
         $ColumnNames = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'supplierprice' AND column_name NOT
IN ('supp_price_id','net_id','region', 'country', 'networkname', 'mcc', 'mnc', 'mnp'
)") or die("mysql error"); 

$columnArray=array();*/


foreach($columnArray as $value) {


//$columnArray[]=$rows1[0];

echo '<td  id="CPH_GridView1_xxx" width="0px;" class="edit '.$value.' '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows[$value].'</td>';   
}   



 echo ' <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientprice" class="edit clientprice '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["clientprice"].'</td>
        <td> <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="edit route '.$rows["net_id"].'" >';         



           // $query = "SELECT route FROM routestable WHERE `clientid` = '$client_id' `"; 
           // print "Query is".$query; 
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
            {  
                echo '<option value="' . $rows['route'] . '"> ' . $rows['route'] .     '</option>';  
               // echo '<option value="Hi"> Hi</option>';
            }   


         echo '</select>
                            </td>

                <td></td>'


        ;

echo '</tr>';

}
}
?>
```

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#mySelect').on('change keyup', function(){
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
        var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

        $.ajax({    type: "POST",
            url:"clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
           data: "value="+$('#mySelect').find(":selected").val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid,
            success: function(data){
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        }});
    });


    $('#editbox').live('blur',function(){
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
});
```

Comment: I see you have some PHP code there. You could tag your question as PHP too and show it correctly; I wouldn't guess what you mean by `.$rows["net_id"].` on the first line if I didn't recognize PHP right away.

Comment: You're not really getting the selects value, as that would be `this.value`, you're getting the value of an element called `client` ?

Comment: You should have given the php code that constructed the mysql statement. You make people try to estimate what would be your code...

Comment: Can you please post your `clientnetworkpricelist/update.php` file code here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.ajax input').val()` is an issue here, please make sure you have an input element in your HTML.

If want to use `mySelect` value in post,

```
data: "value="+$(this).val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid,
```

And also here,

`$('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());`

In that case, you need to use `edit` class selector. ID is unique attribute, thats the reason, it was worked for first one element.

```
             $('.edit').on('keyup change', function(){              

                  arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );

                  var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

                    $.ajax({    type: "POST",
                        url:"clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
                        data: "value="+$(this).val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid,
                        success: function(data){
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    }});
                });
```

Comment: yea i change the code now its working for the first row but for other rows it not performing other rows my edited code data: "value="+$('#mySelect').find(":selected").val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid,

Comment: I can you help you more, If could share your html section here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41347/discussion-between-arokia-and-chinnu-r)

Comment: i need another help after saveing database i need to show the popup window to show the data is saved in database

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of selected option with following:

```
var value2send = $('#mySelect').find(":selected").val();
```

Then you could add it to your data.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @charlietfl this is an another alternative:

```
var value2send = $('#mySelect').val();
```

Comment: redundant to find the options, .val() works fine on select tags

Comment: Updated according to your comment @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

for getting the selected  item on  drop down , there is no need to use CHange Action 
For Example

```
var SlcItem = $('#Your Select').find('option:selected').attr('value');
```