# Ajax search not retrieving dropdown values

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen.js plugin for drop-down search in which I have fetch data successfully also saved it to database but I unable to retrieve those saved drop-down data from database to it's respective field using Ajax search.

I tried initializing chosen in success function but no luck, not giving any output but when I alert the response its working.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
  $('#search').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
    var sid = $("#search").val();
      $.ajax({
                  url: '{{ URL::to('search-data/')}}'+"/"+ sid,
                  type: "Get",
                  dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(response){
                  $("#mob").val(response.mobile);//Working 
                  $("#car").chosen().val(response.car_name);//Not Working
                  $("#car").val(response.car_name);//Not Working
                  //alert(response.car_name);//Working but in alert only
                 }
                });
            }
    });
     });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<label for="car">Car Name</label>
  <select class="form-control select-box" name="car" id="car">
    <option>Select Car</option>
  </select>
</div >
```

I want to retrieve saved drop-down values to its respective field.

[image]

Comment: I think that will get the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030606/jquery-not-getting-the-selected-value-from-dropdown

Comment: You mean like this `$('#car').html($('#car input').val());` or `$('#car').html($('#car input').val(response.car_name));` both are not working...

Comment: what does `response` have in it ? can you post that as well.

Comment: @Swati it contains server response eg. `response.mobile` where mobile is my database column name which returning data but it's not working with drop-downs

Comment: Or is there any other way to do CRUD operations for drop-down? (Drop-down with search) using Ajax and Laravel? because I'm struggling for this since 4 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `options` to your select box and then trigger [updated](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggerable-events) so that the chosen select-box get the updated changes. Working example:

```js
//Suppose you need to append below variable
var response_car_name="abcd";
//append the option and then use trigger event to update select box
   $("#car").chosen().append("<option>"+response_car_name+"</option").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">


<div>
<label for="car">Car Name</label>
  <select name="brand"  id="car"class="form-control select-box " name="car" >
    <option>Select Car</option>
  </select>
</div >
```

Comment: Amazing! your solution works but it returns data in options, it should show at the top, please check this more clarity https://gph.is/g/E3gdObN

Comment: Also when trying to update retrieved drop-down via Ajax it's not working, please check https://www.codepile.net/pile/rQRLVEem

Comment: @glitchy Used `data-placeholder="Select Car"` attribute under `<select..>` tag so that it will automatically show when there are no options ,also use `.html` instead of `.append` under jquery.

Comment: No, now I am getting values as per solution but unable to update/change them, eg previous car name was `Audi` now updating to `Mercedes` https://www.codepile.net/pile/rQRLVEem

Comment: okay , so you need to `empty` select box and add new options to it in `success` function ?

Comment: You can use `$("#car").empty().trigger('chosen:updated');` to empty the select-box and then add new option to it using above code  in success function ,also always use `trigger('chosen:updated')` whenever you make any changes in select-box whether it is updating ,adding etc .

Comment: Ohh.. sorry not in success function, I want to update current retrieved record, please refer this Ajax update data code https://www.codepile.net/pile/PLo8jMAq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199909/discussion-between-swati-and-glitchy).